# Adding API Key from Big Commerce Store

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to add an api key from my bigcommerce store to my developer account.  I go in and add a user that has access to api, and this generates a key, and I click save.  I then registered as developer at developer.bigcommerce.com and tried to add the key, but it gave me an invalid credentials message.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating this and it seems to be working fine. Did you make sure you added the store url too for the new api key.

Look at the attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've inputed the user name and key correctly, you also want to be sure the store url matches the API URL given when you created the new user **BUT** without the /api/v2 at the end.

So if your API URL happened to be `https://store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2`

Just input `https://store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com` for the store url