# BigCommerce Sandbox store

Tags: api, sandbox, bigcommerce

I've signed up for a developer account on BigCommerce and would like to be able to set up my own sandbox style store where I can use the data from my actual store without actually changing anything in production, like how other sandbox developer environments work.  Is this possible?

I know of the big open sandbox for you to play with ([store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com](http://store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com)) but this is open to **all** developer accounts, so I shouldn't work with real data there because other developers could get to it and/or change the same things that I'm working on.

Also I'm having the same issue as [this BigCommerce Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451556/adding-api-key-from-big-commerce-store) as well.  Would adding an API key to the Dashboard have something to do with possibly having a sandbox, since the only API key on the dashboard right now is for the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

sign up for a trial store and we should be able to convert it into a sandbox for you. Just contact us with your trial store url. Thanks!